# How to improve speed creating really big groups and searching through them in Python 3

Tags: python, sudoku, operation

So, I need some help speeding up my program and making it more efficient, so that it doesn't take so much memory a laptop can't handle it. First of all, I'm creating a program to solve sudokus. You enter a plain value (1111111111111111) then, with some manipulations, change some numbers, and then it start to check the validity of the sudoku. If it's not a legal one, it searches if the variable "y", a counter/index like thing, is in one of the group and in the first one it is, it operates some summs. You'll see:

```
tablero = 1111111111111111
g1 = range(4,4294967296,4)
g2 = range(16,4294967296,16)
g3 = range(64,4294967296,64)
g4 = range(256,4294967296,256)
g5 = range(1024,4294967296,1024)
g6 = range(4096,4294967296,4096)
g7 = range(16384,4294967296,16384)
g8 = range(65536,4294967296,65536)
g9 = range(262144,4294967296,262144)
g10 = range(1048576,4294967296,1048576)
g11 = range(4194304,4294967296,4194304)
g12 = range(16777216,4294967296,16777216)
g13 = range(67108864,4294967296,67108864)
g14 = range(268435456,4294967296,268435456)
g15 = range(1073741824,4294967296,1073741824)
g16 = range(500000,4294967296,500000)


y = 1
def nueva_conf():
    global tablero
    global y
    if y in g15:
        tablero = tablero + 700000000000000 - 33333333333333
    elif y in g14:
        tablero = tablero + 70000000000000 - 3333333333333
    elif y in g13:
        tablero = tablero + 7000000000000 - 333333333333
    elif y in g12:
        tablero = tablero + 700000000000 - 33333333333
    elif y in g11:
        tablero = tablero + 70000000000 - 3333333333
    elif y in g10:
        tablero = tablero + 7000000000 - 333333333

    ...

    elif y in g3:
        tablero = tablero + 700 - 33
    elif y in g2:
        tablero = tablero + 70 - 3
    elif y in g1:
        tablero = tablero + 7
    else:
        tablero = tablero + 1

    tablero_copy = tablero
    y = y+1
```

That's the part I need to improve, as it is the one that I think eats a big chunk of my memory. I really don't know how to make it be more efficient. I really want it to work this way, with the operations and all that miscellaneous. I'm already working on another way to solve sudokus, but that's the one I've made independently, without help, and I feel it has it's possibility. What do you think, Python programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking against a list of numbers, just check if the *rule* is true. That's much faster, and can be proceduralized:

```
tablero = 1111111111111111
g_values = [500000, 1073741824, 268435456, 67108864, 16777216, 4194304, 1048576, 262144, 65536, 16384, 4096, 1024, 256, 64, 16, 4, 1]
d_values = [6666666666666667, 666666666666667, 66666666666667, 6666666666667, 666666666667, 66666666667, 6666666667, 666666667, 66666667, 6666667, 666667, 66667, 6667, 667, 67, 7, 1]
y = 1
def nueva_conf():
    global tablero
    global y
    if y > 0 and y <= 4294967296:  # required for all g ranges
        for d, g, i in reversed(zip(d_values, g_values, range(17)):
            if i == 0:
                continue # skip g=500000
            if (y % g) == 0:  # check for divisibility
                tablero += d  # add value
                break         # break out of loop
    tablero_copy = tablero
    y += 1
```

Comment: The problem is, they are not just numbers, they are ranges. I mean, in the g1 group, you have 4 and all it's multiples up to 4294967296 (4,8,12,16,20,24,etc). I'm not sure if your solution contemplates that issue.

Comment: @user3870619 The idea in this answer is that we split up testing "in the group of 4 and it's multiples up to 4294967296" with three requirements: Is it greater than 0, y > 0? Is it less than or equal to 4294967296? Is it a multiple of 4, (y % 4) == 0?  All the numbers in that range, and only the numbers in that range, satisfy these tests.

Comment: You can call me an idiot :') I've implemented your solution and it looks quite better than mine, but, I don't know why, it takes the same 11 seconds to throw the first number after the first 500000 operations in your solution and in mine. Any ideas why? (Thanks for the solution, even after 3 months in it I'm too noob to understand that kind of code)

Comment: @user3870619 I would never call you an idiot! Also, I'm not sure why the time it takes is still large. I'm not sure why my code any the original code run at approximately the same speed. It may be that Python is helping out with an optimization regarding the `range` result.

Comment: :) One last question. I've been trying on my own, but still can't understand how the `for d, g in reversed(zip(d_values[1:], g_values[1:]))`statement works. I mean, you take d and g as local variables, but why do you need to use zip() and can't join it manually, or how does the computer know wich number to take as d and which one as g? Also, it also works without the reversed() method, don't know how/why. I'm using python 3.4, maybe that has something to do with the speed. Thanks for all the help, really.

Comment: `d_values[1:]` and `g_values[1:]` subset their arrays, so that the first element (element 0) isn't included. In retrospect, it's faster to just skip them in the loop (edited). `zip(...)` spits out a tuple of `(d, g)` each time `for` loops over it. The order out of `zip` is the same as the order in, which is how Python knows `d` is before `g`. `reversed()` iterates backwards instead of forward, effectively reversing the order. `for d, g in ...:` reads each tuple into `d` and `g`. Since both `reversed` and `zip` are iterators, they don't require the array to be completely created first.

Comment: @user3870619 Finally, python 3.4 ranges are done much, much more efficiently than python 2.x ranges. In python 3.4, the `in` operator for ranges is actually implemented internally very similarly to (though more generally than) the `(y % g) == 0` line above. This Python under-the-hood optimization is why you didn't see an improvement switching to the above. Indeed, you could have used an array comprehension of ranges instead of g and d values.

Comment: Thank you, really. I'm amused of how this community works. I'm really grateful for helping me solving the issue and helping me understand it. See you!